# What are some well-known Qt apps in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, gui, gtk, qt

I'm trying to decide between using Qt and GTK in ubuntu, but that's not the topic of this question.

I'm looking for some examples of well-known/popular apps in Ubuntu that use Qt/QML. 
I think that most of the applications in Ubuntu are GNOME and thus Gtk, correct? I would like to know what Qt apps look like as differentiated from Gtk apps (which I believe are in the majority(?))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Software_that_uses_Qt)!

Arora, Clementine, Google Earth, Hydrogen, Mathematica, Psi, QBitTorrent, Skype, VirtualBox, VLC, and many other programs. Also, all QT applications will still function perfectly under GNOME.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Andrew says : VLC (probably the most well-known program based on Qt), Clementine, Skype... I would add the (excellent) Opera web browser too.

You can add applications from KDE (which is available on the original Ubuntu, i.e. not only Kubuntu) just like Kate, Konqueror or Amarok for example.